# UIPageViewController template fallback for iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard, fallback

I created an app based on the **PageViewController** template for iOS5 in XCode 4.2.

I am now trying to make it work for iOS versions **prior to 5.0**. Here are the problems that I can think of, but I guess they are not the only ones:

- **Storyboards** are not available before iOS5, so I would have to recode
  everything using nibs. Is there a better way?
- **UIPageViewController** does not exist before iOS 5... How can I replace it with something similar but that works with older versions?

Lastly if I create an app that is iOS5 only, what is roughly the **percentage of the devices** that have been updated so far?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, using nibs is how you work without storyboards.

If you're super hot set on a page curl effect in iOS 4, you could look at

http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/

but it would be a lot of work to get it usable. Much easier to just use a simple scroll view or something like that.

Last I heard about a third had upgraded.